# How to run existing mathematica nb from Java

Tags: java

I have the Mathematica notebook (Test.nb in this case), how can I run in from Java?
So far I have the following code. If I type:

```
UsingFrontEnd[NotebookEvaluate[ToFileName["D:\Test","Test.nb"]]]
```

directly to kernel window, then it evaluates Test.nb, but if I do it using evaluate method (as shown below) - nothing happens, no output, no errors.

```
import com.wolfram.jlink.*;

public class MathCore {

    public MathCore() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void evalMath(String dir,String fname) {

        KernelLink ml = null; 
        String jLinkDir = "C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram Research\\Mathematica\\10.0\\SystemFiles\\Links\\JLink";
        System.setProperty("com.wolfram.jlink.libdir", jLinkDir);

        try { 
            ml = MathLinkFactory.createKernelLink("-linkmode launch -linkname 'C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram Research\\Mathematica\\10.0\\MathKernel.exe'");

            ml.discardAnswer();
            String expr = "UsingFrontEnd[NotebookEvaluate[ToFileName[\""+dir+"\", \""+fname+"\"]]]";
            System.out.println(expr);
            ml.evaluate(expr);
            ml.waitForAnswer();
            //ml.close();
            String x = ml.getString();
            System.out.println("Result = " + x);

        } catch (MathLinkException e) { 
            System.out.println("Fatal error opening link: " + 
            e.getMessage()); 
            return; 
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Mathematica notebooks are not programs/scripts and are not meant to be run as a unit.  Why don't you put the code in a plain text file with the `.m` extension instead, and run it using `Get`?  It will not require a front end. Notebooks can be converted to .m files.

Comment: Can you please explain it in more details or give some link?

Comment: Actually, @Szabolcs, I would claim that this code *should* work.  But it is an unfortunate truth that the history of `NotebookEvaluate` running from a standalone kernel is a troubled one.  I believe the relevant issue here is that there is a known and reported bug that, if a kernel has a parent link other than the FE, then `UsingFrontEnd[NotebookEvaluate[...]]` can fail.  I partially fixed this for 10.3, but troubles remain.  That having been said, there is a minor bug in the code here.  See next comment.

Comment: @KonstantinStolpovsky, in the short run, you're probably going to have to work with Szabolcs' solution, which is to use a package file.  Because of bugs I mentioned in my previous comment.  But that having been said, your code has a completely unnecessary reference to `EvaluatePacket` in it.  You may wish to correct it in your question.

Comment: you need a .m file, read the beginning of this answer.
 http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95785/evaluate-notebook-from-other-notebook/95791#95791
Also this one
http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94236/evaluate-multiple-notebooks-sequentially-and-automatically/94263#94263

Comment: @JohnFultz, carrected as advised. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Szabolcs,  It is absolutely clear how to create script from nb, but the question of how to run it from Java remains.

Comment: @JohnFultz & Konstantin, I didn't mean that the code shouldn't work.  I just pointed out that in order to run some Mathematica code it is not necessary to deal with notebook and the Front End.  Just running the code from an .m file is easier.  Of course there *can* be good reasons to run the code from a notebook sometimes ...

Comment: @Konstantin I'm sorry, unfortunately I cannot help you with Java. I could show how to do it from C, but I am not familiar enough with Java to attempt writing working code for this (unless I'm really pressed :)

Comment: @Szabolcs, can you explain how to run .m package from Kernel with `Get`?

Comment: @Konstantin [Simply evaluate `Get["yourfile.m"]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Get.html).  Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: Thenk you guys, you are the best!

Comment: The only thing I had to change is this: `String expr="Get[ToFileName[\"D:\\Mathematica\\CarbonateDissolution\", \"Test.m\"]]";`Also, in evaluated .m package one needs to use explicit dir path instead of something like `SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];`