# Open, Evaluate and Close notebooks sequentially

Tags: programming, evaluation, notebooks

I wanna Open, Evaluate and Close notebooks sequentially.

Code from [question here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94236/evaluate-multiple-notebooks-sequentially-and-automatically)

```
nb1 = NotebookOpen["/Users/you/Documents/1.nb"];
SelectionMove[nb1, All, Notebook]
SelectionEvaluate[nb1]
nb2 = NotebookOpen["/Users/you/Documents/2.nb"];
SelectionMove[nb2, All, Notebook]
SelectionEvaluate[nb2]
```

nearly works, but opens notebooks simultaneously at first.

How to do it so notebook1 Opens, Evaluates and Closes, and then notebook2 does the same, notebook 3 and so on...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a function to monitor the evaluation of the notebook evaluation, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8054270/879601

Note, this requires use of a second kernel in case the monitoring kernel clashes with the executing kernel.

```
NotebookPauseForEvaluation[nb_] := Module[{},
  While[NotebookEvaluatingQ[nb], Pause[.25]]]

NotebookEvaluatingQ[nb_] := Module[{},
  SelectionMove[nb, All, Notebook];
  Or @@ Map["Evaluating" /. # &, Developer`CellInformation[nb]]]

UsingFrontEnd[nb1 = NotebookOpen["/Users/you/Documents/1.nb"];
  SetOptions[nb1, Evaluator -> "Test"];
  SelectionMove[nb1, All, Notebook];
  SelectionEvaluate[nb1];
  NotebookPauseForEvaluation[nb1];
 ];

nb2 = NotebookOpen["/Users/you/Documents/2.nb"];
SelectionMove[nb2, All, Notebook]
SelectionEvaluate[nb2]
```